# Signal break-codes in Linux

Tags: linux, signals, irix

I am porting a code from IRIX to Linux RedHat, that is currently using signal handlers with the form of

```
void sig_handler (int sig, int code, struct sigcontext *).
```

These codes are for example BRK_USERBP, BRK_SSTEPBP, BRK_OVERFLOW, BRK_DIVZERO and BRK_MULOVF.

My searches have shown that Linux doesn't support it. Does it?

If not, what equivalent/replacement can I use instead?

I have seen si_code in siginfo_t in [sigaction](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), but it doesn't seem right for this purpose.

Thanks!

Comment: from reading the manpage, si_code seems to do exactly what you're looking for. e.g.: *The following values can be placed in si_code for a SIGTRAP signal: ``TRAP_BRKPT``: process breakpoint […]*

Comment: Thanks. But it seems a bit lack of compatibility... now _BRK_USERBP_ and _BRK_SSTEPBP_ will be the same (_TRAP_BRKPT_, as you said), and didn't find any equivalent for _BRK_MULOVF_.

Comment: Is mulovf a multiplication overflow? If so, thats probably handled by SIGFPE or something.

Comment: Most important question, what are those signals supposed to do in the code you are porting? SIGFPE is a signal bucket that handles most FPU faults.